# For MySQL, how to INSERT the result of a SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

For MySQL, how to INSERT the result of a SELECT statement? I tried

```
SET @input1 = 1;
SET @input2 = 2;
INSERT INTO
    my_table (col1, col2)
SELECT
    @input1 AS col1,
    @input2 AS col2
WHERE
    @input1 > 0
        AND
    @input2 > 0;
```

which gives a message:

> [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE @input1 > 0 AND @input2 > 0' at line 6

Any idea how to fix it?

Here is a related article I found on this `INSERT`-`SELECT` approach to do conditional insert:

https://timmurphy.org/2013/10/23/conditional-insert-in-sql/

But it seems it does not work for MySQL which requires a `FROM` clause for `SELECT`?

Comment: You can't have a `where` clause without a `from` clause.

Comment: `FROM dual` is the kludge to get past the syntax error.  But xzilla's answer is probably much better.

Comment: If you edit your "my intention" comment on xzilla's answer into the original post this would be a reasonable question. As it stands it's simply a basic syntax error & likely to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic syntax for this generally involves inserting into one table by selecting from another, which would look something like:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (a1, b1)
     SELECT a2, b2 
       FROM t2
      WHERE a2 > 0
            AND
            b2 > 0
;
```

There is some flexibility in that, although perhaps not as much as you are looking for. It might be worth looking at [the mysql docs for insert-select](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) for more information.

Comment: I just added `SET @input1 = 1; SET @input2 = 2;` into my original post. It happens that my two values are manually set. In this case, what is the right `FROM ...`?

Comment: My intention is to make the `INSERT` conditional such that only when the two input values are positive, the tuple will get inserted. Maybe there is a better way than this INSERT-SELECT approach.